# When will Jython support Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jython

According to [Jython's documentation](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#IsJythonthesamelanguageasPython.3F):

> Jython is an implementation of the
>   Python language for the Java platform.
>   Jython 2.5 implements the same
>   language as CPython 2.5, and nearly
>   all of the Core Python standard
>   library modules. (CPython is the C
>   implementation of the Python
>   language.) Jython 2.5 uses the same
>   regression test suite as CPython, with
>   some minor modifications.

Are there any plans to support Python 3? If so, when is it scheduled to be released?

Comment: Found this was wondering the same thing today, 7 years on. I see that IronPython has been picked up again... but still no Jython.

Comment: No change in Jython 3 repository since 18 July 2017 so it doesn't look good. But Jython 2 is still active, there's a chance activity on Jython 3 restarts in 2020 if Python 2 actually stops being supported. It's purely speculative.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Jython roadmap is definitely outdated.
However, on Frank Wierzbicki's Weblog (one of Jython's main developers) you can get [an update](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.com/2008/10/updated-jython-roadmap.html), telling that Python 3 is definitely on the radar.

Unfortunately, it is not yet clear when, as it is stated in a [comment in that same blog](https://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=14276139&postID=4324280851240781269) from 2010:

> Jython will reach 2.6 and later a 3.x,
>   but it's hard to give a solid time
>   frame. I'm hoping to get a 2.6 out in
>   a few months.

In an interview in 2017, Wierzbicki stated that Python 3 is desirable but difficult.

> Langfristig wollen wir eine 3.x-Version
>   veröffentlichen, aber das ist ein langwieriger Prozess, weil es eine
>   große Menge an Veränderungen in der 3.x-Serie gab.

English:

> We want to publish a version 3.x in the long run, but that is a drawn-out
>   process, because there were a lot of changes in the 3.x series.

[Jython – Python in der Java-Welt [Pirates of the JVM]](https://jaxenter.de/jython-jvm-pirates-52427), JAXenter, 2017-04-12.

Comment: Great find! I was sure that this question must have been asked *somewhere*, but my Google-fu was lacking. :)

Comment: Just looked for "jython roadmap" ;-)

Comment: This was posted over 2 years ago and searches right now are still lacking. It looks like Jython 3 isn't anywhere except the dev's heads atm.

Comment: As you can see on that blog, the main contributor had to stop working on Jython for a while; now they are approaching 2.7, and 3.0 should be next step.

Comment: 5+ years later, [Jython 2.7 is out](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.fi/2015/05/jython-270-final-released.html).

Comment: In a German interview with Frank Wierzbicki, dated April 2017, he states that "in the long term, we want to publish a 3.x version, but that is a lengthy process."
https://jaxenter.de/jython-jvm-pirates-52427

Comment: @MarcoEckstein: Thanks for pointing this out. I edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 56):

**2023 update**: a [March 2023 commit](https://github.com/jython/jython3/commit/e0d80bbddff0d5465f2da3f9de52bff89ab00e53) provides an update on the situation:

> The latest released version of Jython remains 2.7.x (see [Jython](https://github.com/jython/jython) for that).
>
> This doesn't mean that there isn't any progress on a Jython 3. A lot of exploration has taken place away from the official repository, in order not to pollute it with false starts and dead-ends.
>
> Since the beginning of 2021, Jython 3 exploratory work reached a form that merited porting from the experiment to the main of the official repo. Risky design concepts still begin life in the exploratory environment, then arrive as a PR to the official main branch. Please watch the jython-dev mailing list for developements, or the [main branch](https://github.com/jython/jython/tree/main) (not master) of the official Jython repo.

---

**Another update**: an [August 2020 commit](https://github.com/jython/jython3/commit/def4f8ec47cb7a9c799ea4c745f12badf92c5769) clarified that the repository to look at is not the [Jython3](https://github.com/jython/jython3) one but the [main Jython repo](https://github.com/jython/jython). Anyway "The latest version of Jython remains 2.7.x. A Jython 3.x should appear, but exploratory work towards it is not stable at the time of writing.
Please watch the jython-dev mailing list for developements."

---

**Update**: 9 years after the question has been originally asked the answer now seems to be **not in the near future**. [Most recent commit](https://github.com/jython/jython3/commit/5b4dc2d54d01a6fda8c55d07b2608167e7a40769) is now more than two years old (July 18, 2017), and [developers say that the 3.x branch is "resting"](https://github.com/jython/jython3/issues/36#issuecomment-484452223).

---

**My original answer**:

5 years after the question has been asked, the answer is still "it will come, but the time frame for an initial release is not clear yet".

What we can say is that now there is a [jython3 repository](https://github.com/jython/jython3) targetting Python 3.5. `README.md`, dated 28 May 2015, says:

> This repo is in the very early stages of development of a release of Jython 3.5. Planned goals are language and runtime compatibility with CPython 3.5, along with continued substantial support of the Python ecosystem.

[Jython FAQ page](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#What_is_the_current_status_of_Jython.3F) states that:

> Jython 3.x development is in progress.

Comment: @BhabaniSankarMishra looking at the commit history, it's mildly alive https://github.com/jython/jython3/commits/master but I wouldn't count on Jython 3 being officially released anytime soon.

Comment: It looks moribund. No commits since  Jul 18, 2017. Sad.

Comment: See also https://github.com/jython/jython3/issues/36. Frank Wierzbicki wrote on Mar 1, 2018: "Jython3 is more stalled than dead". Jeff Allen wrote on Apr 18, 2019: It's not dead, it's resting".

Comment: Appears to be a dead parrot

Answer (score 11):

I suggest looking elsewhere for a Python 3 interpreter on the JVM.

The GraalPython project (https://github.com/graalvm/graalpython) looks promissing. There is good rationale behind its existence, essentially it says "Let's support scientific computing and data analysis in Python, which means e.g. numpy, including native-code modules, and let's make it fast and interoperable".

Jython, not so much, at this point.

Comment: But then the huge différence is cpu intensive code using objects that can t be serialized have to remain single threaded like with Cpython (Jython is gil less).

Comment: I briefly checked and it indeed looks like GIL is present in GraalPython. Lets see what the answer to comment https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/issues/180#issuecomment-754315123 will be ;P

Comment: I m the author of the comment. That s why per thread performance is still the underlying reason when choossing the cpu (and thus having to stay with Intel abi instead of longsun or arm). Because of a poor design decision in the language. I m needing Python3 and the objects I m using can t be serialized which means a Python3 implementation of Python without the gil (or making it optional) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most up to date info on the Jython Website https://www.jython.org/jython-3-roadmap but without timescales.