# Python compiler written in Java

Tags: python

I am looking for open source implementations of python compilers written purely in Java, preferably those that support Python 3. I started with jython but it only supports Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe such a thing exists yet. If it does its in pre-alpha and probably isn't stable or well documented. Jython is probably still your best bet, and apparently support for Python 3 is coming to Jython but the timetable is still unclear. See [this stack overflow question for more on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351008/when-will-jython-support-python-3)

However one advantage of Jython is that you can use any Java classes as if they were Python modules. **What features were you planning on using that are only supported by Python 3?** Because it is entirely possible (and actually very likely) that you can reproduce those features using Python 2.7, Java or a combo of the two.

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit the link? (it got messed up)
I'm mostly looking for a parser and simply error checking passes (if they exist), and I am just too lazy to roll out my own ASTs :)

Comment: Updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you're just looking to error check your python, I certainly don't blame you for not wanting to roll your own AST (sounds like a nightmare). Have you considered simply attempting to compile the code to a .pyc? Obviously won't be any runtime consideration but you can do this using the python 'compileall' module. I can give you an example if you think it'd be useful.

Comment: I'm actually hoping to reuse the compiler frontend to implement my own code analysis. Thanks for the link anyways.

Comment: No worries, hope it was a helpful answer.